# How to build multi-step form in phoenix liveviews?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm new to elixir and Phoenix liveviews and I'm currently facing a problem to create a multi-step form.

I'm actually using a embedded schema for which is combined of schema `user` and `user_profile`. This needs to be a multistep form where on step one `email` field should be visible and on step 2 `phone_number`, `password` and `confirm_password` should be entered.

Is there any way to implement this in liveviews like we do in other frontend frameworks?
Any help will be appreciated, Thanks

I've tried to do it using components but couldn't figured out how to do it.

Comment: There's a few approaches handling step wizards, [this blog post](https://bernheisel.com/blog/liveview-multi-step-form) gives a thorough explanation, you should be able to find many more examples using the 'form wizard' term in combination with 'phoenix live view'.

Comment: @Hed Somehow Markus changed the url it seems. It's available here:https://dev.to/tuacker/multi-step-form-using-phoenix-live-view-2i85